# How to derive this interesting identity for $\log(\sin(x))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I saw on SE that:

$$\log(\sin x)=-\log(2)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n} \phantom{a} (0<x<\pi)$$

This is an extremely useful identity, as it helps solve:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \log(\sin(x)) dx$$

But how is it derived? From Taylor series, power series? How do I get this?

Even if someone can start me off that would be great.

Comment: And BTW, $\log\sin$ has elementary primitive: http://es.numberempire.com/integralcalculator.php?function=log%28sin%28x%29%29&var=x.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla What is obvious to one person is not necessarily obvious to other, that's what this is all about.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It's only elementary if you consider the polylogarithm to be elementary. Not many people do, I think.

Comment: @DanielR, the formula is so long that I have not seen the polylogarithms ah the end! :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $~\ln(1-t)~=~-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}n~$ in conjunction with [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).