# Show that $\log(\sin(x)) = -\log(2) + ...$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Show that:

$$\log(\sin(x)) = -\log(2) - \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}$$

$$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$\log(\sin(x)) =  \log(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) - \log(2i)$$

$$= \log(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) - \log(2) - \frac{i \pi}{2}$$

What next?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068879/how-to-derive-this-interesting-identity-for-log-sinx) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159843/computing-the-series-of-log-and-sine) and [here for the full solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=e^{ix}[1-e^{-2ix}]$$

$$\ln[e^{ix}-e^{-ix}]=ix+\ln[1-e^{-2ix}]$$

Now $\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}r$

Use [Euler formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and equate the real and the imaginary parts

See also: [Convergence for log 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/convergence-for-log-2)

Comment: Wait so using: $$\sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} = \frac{1 - e^{2ix}}{2}$$

Comment: @Lebes, No. We have $$\ln(1-e^{-2ix})=-\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(e^{-2ix})^r}r$$  Now $(e^{-2ix})^r=e^{-i2rx}=\cos(2rx)-i\sin(2rx)$

Comment: Okay so:

$$\log(1- e^{-2ix}) = -\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2rx)}{r} + i\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2rx)}{r}$$

But how to elimate $\sin$? @lab

Comment: @Lebes, The answer has "equate the real and the imaginary parts"

Comment: I see. let the expression by $H$. Then: $\Im H = \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2rx)}{r}$. And on the LHS it is $0i$ hence: 

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2rx)}{r}$$ Doesnt exist. So: 

$$\log(1 - e^{-2ix}) = -\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2rx)}{r}$$

And:

$$1 - e^{-2ix} = 2\sin^2(x)$$

So:

$$\log(\sin^2(x)) - \log(2) = -\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}...$$

That isnt correct though @lab